# What is the value of participating in proposal-writing efforts, for a postdoc researcher?

Tags: publications, funding, postdocs

I am a young researcher already having published several papers, and in the same time I have participated several times in bids for national and European (fp7, h2020) projects. So I could say I have some experience in proposal-writing.

I am now preparing my cv to apply for a lecturer position in UK. The question is: should I highlight this experience in my cv (i.e. provide more details about the bids in which I participated, my role, the outcome etc), or hiring committees are mostly focused on publications? How important is fund attraction at a lecturer level? I am asking because I see that this kind of experience is often mentioned in the desired (not the essential) qualifications of the applicant.

An other point of view over the same issue is this: If I have the chance to avoid being involved in proposal-writing efforts, should I? That is, of course, in order to continue with my research (i.e. focus on papers).

Moreover, how can one's claims be verified? How do you prove that you are telling the truth and not over-selling yourself, regarding your participation and experience? Isn't this part of your cv a part that is less verifiable?

Comment: Regarding the verification part: I would expect that usually whoever is the formal PI on the proposal you worked on will be one of your letter writers, and can thus point out there how much of a help you were.

Comment: ... and even if the PI did not write a formal letter on your behalf, people *know* each other in academia, and people on a search committee can simply call the person you give as the PI on a proposal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, your titular question:

> What is the value of participating in proposal-writing efforts, for a postdoc researcher?

Especially in Europe, and when applying for faculty positions, the value is *huge*. Successfully playing the grant game is nowadays what keeps the lights on in many European universities, at least research-wise. Having a track record in this dimension can easily be viewed as even more desirable than a great research track record (although, of course, you will still need at least good publications).

> should I highlight this experience in my cv (i.e. provide more details about the bids in which I participated, my role, the outcome etc)

Yes, you should definitely highlight this somewhere in your application (not sure if the CV is the right place, though). Your letters may or may not be a good place, if LoR are considered important for the job you are applying to.

> If I have the chance to avoid being involved in proposal-writing efforts, should I?

This is an interesting question, and mainly depends on what your grant and research track records look like at the moment. If you have not actually been involved in grant proposals, I would certainly recommend getting this experience. If your research track record is lacking, I would focus on research. Realistically, you will need a good record in both dimensions to be competitive for faculty positions.

> Moreover, how can one's claims be verified? How do you prove that you are telling the truth and not over-selling yourself, regarding your participation and experience? Isn't this part of your cv a part that is less verifiable?

In the optimal case, you have won some grants in your own name. But even if this is not the case, the experienced recruiter knows what to look for and who to ask to figure out whether you are overselling yourself. Keep in mind that researchers are connected and EU projects are large - *somebody* in the hiring faculty will know *somebody* who was involved in your project and give them a ring to ask them whether you actually did what you claim you did. If that's also not possible, the recruiting faculty will just ask you a few questions regarding the claim they are interested in, and observe your reaction.

Answer (score 1):

I think a critical component of being a scientific postdoc is to gain experience with writing and submitting research proposals and papers.  While I understand the concern that postdocs often do NOT get the credit they deserve when assisting with proposals, the benefit is more typically indirect and usually becomes critical experience when postdocs are writing their own research proposals for academic jobs or as independent scientists.